# Same type-name exists in both Aero and Aero2

Tags: c#, upgrade, uwp-xaml, .net-6.0

I am updating several projects from .net framework 4.7.2 to .net6, using the excellent upgrade-assistant tool. Sometimes I get this error:

*Error  CS0433  The type 'SystemDropShadowChrome' exists in both 'PresentationFramework.Aero, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'PresentationFramework.Aero2, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'*

This always happens with .xaml-files, and always with the Aero and Aero2 packages. These are both referenced by the **Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF** (C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\6.0.4) framework, which upgrade-assistant adds to my project when upgrading.

I can't remove the Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF framework from my project, of course, but reading about the error CS0433 hints me there should be a way to choose between the packages. Except I cannot find out how to..

Anyone able to help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you show some sample code where you have used `SystemDropShadowChrome`?

Because normally the namespace is declared like this in the xaml-file:
`xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2"`

I faced the same issue (but I have used `SystemDropShadowChrome` in code-behind) and the solution was this workaround: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/765#issuecomment-555163388

You need to modify your `.csproj`-file as following:

1. Add this property-group and select which theme you want to choose (e.g. `Aero2`)

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <ReferenceWpfAeroTheme>false</ReferenceWpfAeroTheme>
    <ReferenceWpfAero2Theme>true</ReferenceWpfAero2Theme>
    <ReferenceWpfAeroLiteTheme>false</ReferenceWpfAeroLiteTheme>
    <ReferenceWpfClassicTheme>false</ReferenceWpfClassicTheme>
    <ReferenceWpfLunaTheme>false</ReferenceWpfLunaTheme>
    <ReferenceWpfRoyaleTheme>false</ReferenceWpfRoyaleTheme>
</PropertyGroup>
```

2. Add this target to the end of the file:

```xml
<Target Name="SelectWpfThemeAssembly" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences" Condition="'$(ReferenceWpfAeroTheme)' == 'true'     Or&#xD;&#xA;                     '$(ReferenceWpfAero2Theme)' == 'true'    Or&#xD;&#xA;                     '$(ReferenceWpfAeroLiteTheme)' == 'true' Or&#xD;&#xA;                     '$(ReferenceWpfClassicTheme)' == 'true'  Or &#xD;&#xA;                     '$(ReferenceWpfLunaTheme)' == 'true'     Or&#xD;&#xA;                     '$(ReferenceWpfRoyaleTheme)' == 'true'">
        <ItemGroup>
            <_WpfThemeAssemblies Include="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(ReferencePath.NuGetPackageId)'=='Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref'  And &#xD;&#xA;                                   '%(ReferencePath.FileName)'=='PresentationFramework.Aero'">
                <Aliases Condition="'$(WpfAeroThemeAliases)'!=''">$(WpfAeroThemeAliases)</Aliases>
            </_WpfThemeAssemblies>

            <_WpfThemeAssemblies Include="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(ReferencePath.NuGetPackageId)'=='Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref'  And &#xD;&#xA;                                   '%(ReferencePath.FileName)'=='PresentationFramework.Aero2'">
                <Aliases Condition="'$(WpfAero2ThemeAliases)'!=''">$(WpfAero2ThemeAliases)</Aliases>
            </_WpfThemeAssemblies>

            <_WpfThemeAssemblies Include="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(ReferencePath.NuGetPackageId)'=='Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref'  And &#xD;&#xA;                                   '%(ReferencePath.FileName)'=='PresentationFramework.AeroLite'">
                <Aliases Condition="'$(WpfAeroLiteThemeAliases)'!=''">$(WpfAeroLiteThemeAliases)</Aliases>
            </_WpfThemeAssemblies>

            <_WpfThemeAssemblies Include="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(ReferencePath.NuGetPackageId)'=='Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref'  And &#xD;&#xA;                                   '%(ReferencePath.FileName)'=='PresentationFramework.Classic'">
                <Aliases Condition="'$(WpfClassicThemeAliases)'!=''">$(WpfClassicThemeAliases)</Aliases>
            </_WpfThemeAssemblies>

            <_WpfThemeAssemblies Include="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(ReferencePath.NuGetPackageId)'=='Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref'  And &#xD;&#xA;                                   '%(ReferencePath.FileName)'=='PresentationFramework.Luna'">
                <Aliases Condition="'$(WpfLunaThemeAliases)'!=''">$(WpfLunaThemeAliases)</Aliases>
            </_WpfThemeAssemblies>


            <_WpfThemeAssemblies Include="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(ReferencePath.NuGetPackageId)'=='Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref'  And &#xD;&#xA;                                   '%(ReferencePath.FileName)'=='PresentationFramework.Royale'">
                <Aliases Condition="'$(WpfRoyaleThemeAliases)'!=''">$(WpfRoyaleThemeAliases)</Aliases>
            </_WpfThemeAssemblies>


            <ReferencePath Remove="@(_WpfThemeAssemblies)" />

            <ReferencePath Include="@(_WpfThemeAssemblies)" Condition="('%(_WpfThemeAssemblies.FileName)'=='PresentationFramework.Aero' And '$(ReferenceWpfAeroTheme)'=='true')          Or &#xD;&#xA;                                ('%(_WpfThemeAssemblies.FileName)'=='PresentationFramework.Aero2' And '$(ReferenceWpfAero2Theme)'=='true')        Or &#xD;&#xA;                                ('%(_WpfThemeAssemblies.FileName)'=='PresentationFramework.AeroLite' And '$(ReferenceWpfAeroLiteTheme)'=='true')  Or &#xD;&#xA;                                ('%(_WpfThemeAssemblies.FileName)'=='PresentationFramework.Classic' And '$(ReferenceWpfClassicTheme)'=='true')    Or &#xD;&#xA;                                ('%(_WpfThemeAssemblies.FileName)'=='PresentationFramework.Luna' And '$(ReferenceWpfLunaTheme)'=='true')          Or&#xD;&#xA;                                ('%(_WpfThemeAssemblies.FileName)'=='PresentationFramework.Royale' And '$(ReferenceWpfRoyaleTheme)'=='true')" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this actually solved the problem. I have tried these settings before but could not work it out on my own.